# How to apply a function to each element of a linspace without using a for-loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Starting with a linspace

```
t = np.linspace(0,10, 100)
```

and an array

```
a = np.array([1,2,44,2, 13,...])
```

I would like to get an array `b`, of the same length of the `linspace` whose elements are the array `a` raised to the power of the linspace elements (without using a for-loop). So you'd have something like

```
b[0]=np.array([1^t[0], 2^t[0], 44^t[0],...])
b[1]=np.array([1^t[1], 2^t[1], 44^t[1],...])
```

etc for the whole linspace.

Since I don't want to use a for-loop, is it possible to  use `np.apply_along_axis` to perform a function on every element of `t` that gives me the final `b` I want? I've been struggling to do this, I think because I must just not understand how `np.apply_along_axis` works entirely.

Comment: `applly_along_axis` is a convenience tool (not performance) for iterating over all dimensions of ONE array - except one.  1d slices of that array will be passed to your function.  You have 2 1d arrays - a totally different task.  Don't let the word "apply" mislead you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

If you raise an array `a` of shape `(N,)` or `(1, N)` (a row vector) to an array  `t` of shape `(M, 1)` (a column vector), numpy automatically broadcasts their shapes and returns an array of shape `(M, N)`, where the `i, j`th element of that array is `a[j]**t[i]`. To represent your `t` array as a column vector, index it as `t[:, None]`, which adds a dimension after the current one.

```
a = np.array([1,2,44,2, 13,...])
t = np.linspace(0,10, 100)

b = a**t[:, None]
```